# Show badge count instead of just a tick on badges page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, user-interface

When going on the "/badges" page on a StackExchange website.  All you are presented with a tick next to badges you have achieved.

[image: Unlocked Citizen Patrol badge]

In my opinion is perfect for badges that can only be achieved once, but for those you can unlock more than once, e.g. Enlightened.

[image: Unlocked Enlightened badge]

Instead of just showing a tick on these types of badges, instead show a number in the green circle (or whatever design is applicable for the website).

I understand that this could cause problems if say the badge was earned #### times.  In this case it could just show a +.  Then if the number was shown on mouse-over it could say ("Earned badge 1643 times.")  Leaving the UI nice and compact.

Comment: One note: At the moment the Badges-Page is cached with generic-values (same page for everyone), that change would require that it is build for every user. That's a *lot* of pages to be built.

Comment: @WaffelizedBobby Sure, but the ticks are already personalised.

Comment: Oh, missed that, true, scratch my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Although this information is already available if you click through to the badge's page or if you view the badges in your profile, the process to get to this page is easier than both of those.

So, in favor of ease, this would definitely be worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

The badge detail page will now show you whether you have earned the badge or not.

Where a badge has been awarded to you multiple times, the checkmark tooltip will display how many times it has been.

With you in rev 2014.4.29.1577 (meta rev 2014.4.29.2200).