# Show badge attainment status on per-badge page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, badges

While reading the [StackOverflow election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election), I noticed that when I click through to information about a particular badge, e.g. [Civic Duty](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/32/civic-duty), it doesn't show whether I've obtained that badge.

I realise I can see this information in other ways, but would it be possible to include my own badge count on this page, e.g.

[image: Proposed badge status image]

Whether a basic tick is shown or a badge count, I'm not overly fussed. I guess we should err on the side of a count, as [this has been requested in other pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144587/show-badge-count-instead-of-just-a-tick-on-badges-page).

Comment: I was just thinking of a similar feature: Showing progress towards a badge. You show "`Civic Duty` Voted 300 or more times", I'd like to see "`Civic Duty` Voted 300 or more times (you've voted 280 times)".

Comment: @jimhark While that does sound lovely, it would be a significantly more challenging feature to implement (i.e. custom per-badge metrics). I've opted for simplicity here in the hope it may get implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The badge detail page will now show you whether you have earned the badge or now.

Where a badge has been awarded to you multiple times, the checkmark tooltip will display how many times it has been.

With you in rev 2014.4.29.1577 (meta rev 2014.4.29.2200).

Comment: Next time answer first, edit later, lol! People here are just too quick. ;-)

Comment: You mean impatient ;)

Comment: Some devs even go as far as waiting until it's live but the risk of forgetting is too big so personally prfer your way. :)